# ASP.NET MVC 2 - Set ViewData on every request in specific area (without inheritance)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

In the "Admin" area of my application, an object must be available in `ViewData` on every page (for display in the Master template). I have already inherited from `Controller`, so I cannot make a simple base class that handles it. What is a good solution of doing this when not using inheritance? An `ActionFilter` seems interesting but I don't want to put it on every controller in the Admin area. I'm considering the following:

- Custom ControllerFactory that detects Area as well
- Application_BeginRequest(), though I have no knowledge on executing controller then.

Maybe you have a better solution?

Comment: What kind of data is it? Maybe Html.RenderAction() is a better solution?

Comment: It's the currently logged in user, so it has dependencies on both database and IPrincipal.

Comment: Ok, I see. I would probably use Html.RenderAction() then. In my opinion that is the most clean solution.

Comment: Yes, it seems very simple to do that instead of mucking around with a ControllerFactory. If you post an answer I'll credit you. Tack! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would create a separate action that executes a partial view that shows the data you need. In my opinion this is the most clean solution for this kind of problem and it's easily testable and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

i have a dropdown on my masterpage. you dont need viewdata for it. i did it like this

code on masterpage:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("schselectr", MVC2_NASTEST.MvcApplication.masterSchooljaarList())%>
```

in Global.asax.cs

```
    public static SelectList masterSchooljaarList() {
        NASDataContext _db = new NASDataContext();
        List<Schooljaar> newlist = _db.Schooljaars.ToList();
        return new SelectList(_db.Schooljaars.ToList(), "Sch_Schooljaar", "Sch_Schooljaar");
    }
```

so simply, it calls the method, which returns the data i need, every time you load the page. easy, clean, effective.

Comment: I just commented that the data object is the currently logged in user, so has dependencies on both database and IPrincipal. Making a static context in a test-friendly framework like this isn't a good solution anyway. But thanks for answering of course!

Comment: cant you send the IPrincipal with it?

            <%= Html.DropDownList("schselectr", MVC2_NASTEST.MvcApplication.masterSchooljaarList(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity))%>

Comment: The reason you don't want to do it this way is because it violates a lot of design patterns (including mvc) and it is hard to test.